# How to add Java compile-time Custom annotation to Protobuf generated code

Tags: java, annotations, protocol-buffers, jacoco, generated

I use gRPC framework with Proto 3. We have a java code coverage tool Jacoco which scans java byte code for java "annotation" @Generated  in compiled classes and if it has one, it skips that java class from coverage. But Proto-compiler adds this annotation:

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(
    value = "by gRPC proto compiler (version 1.20.0)",
    comments = "Source: myProto.proto")
public class MyClass {
...
}
```

But the annotation javax.annotation.Generated has @Retention(value=SOURCE) which doesn't exist in compiled classes.

Is there a way to add annotation to java generated files from protobuf as compile-time?

Comment: Were you able to find a way to do this? Bumping into this same problem (We use lombox as well, but lombok generated annotation is skipped properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an old question, but still

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/42

So you suppose to add `--java_out=annotate_code` to the list of `protoc` options.

If you use https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin gradle plugin for code generation, then you can do like this(Gradle Kotlin DSL):

```
protobuf {
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach { task ->
            task.builtins {
                getByName("java") {
                    option("annotate_code")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, as the `annotate_code` option annotates with `javax.annotation.Generated`, but the question is specifically asking about a **custom** annotation. `javax.annotation.Generated` has source retention, which means tools that look at the .class files, like Jacoco, cannot see it. To make matters worse, the `annotate_code` option does not annotate nested classes.